# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: android, double, number-formatting, numberformatexception, decimalformat

I get this exception from time to time, when I get a new location coordinate from the GPS, and I want to format it.

This is my code:

```
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");
            location.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(location.getLatitude())));
            location.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(location.getLongitude())));
```

Why does this happen? The latitude and longitude that I get back from the location are both Doubles. I format it transforming it into the needed format (5 decimals after point) and then when I try to make a double back, it crashes. Why does this happen? And why not everytime, just sometimes?

Example on what crashed:

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException
 Invalid double: "52,36959"
```

This is where I use it:

```
Log.i("","enteredd latitude is:" + location.getLatitude());
            try{
                DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");
                location.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(location.getLatitude()).replace(",", ".")));
                location.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(location.getLongitude()).replace(",", ".")));
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("","enteredd error deimal formating" + e.getMessage());
            }
            Log.i("","enteredd latitude is:" + location.getLatitude());
```

And the same thing for:

```
location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(PSLocationCenter.getInstance().mLocationClient);
```

Question: Will it fix it if I do it like this?

```
 location.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(location.getLatitude()).replace(",", ".")));
```

Comment: What are the values of `location.getLongitude()` and `location.getLongitude()` ?

Comment: I don't know. I caught the crashes on Fabric. It uses this a lot, like atleast 6 times a minute, untill 60 if the correct activity is openned. And I got "only" 15 crashed in 3 days.
All I know is that I get: Invalid double: "52,36959" So I'm guessing the lat will be something similar to 52,36959xxx

Comment: And therefore the parsing for the double will fail since it contains the comma character.

Comment: I need to edit the comma into a "."? If that is the issue, then why doesn't It crash all the time? I mean, I should always get locations with decimals

Comment: Where's location getting its data? Some external API? You should understand why you're getting sometimes these values that not seems to be a legitimate values for a location.

Comment: I do this in the first line of "onLocationChanged(final Location location)" of the google api. Made some logs now, and will check and edit with some locations

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to google it and read some google docs about the API.

Comment: Share it that so other users that will get here would know as well.

Comment: I'm confused. What is exactly the problem? I mean I get it's the "," but where does it come from? That  I do not get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting a double value into a decimal format, then parsing it back to double and using the very same value that you have gotten from the variable `location` to set the values for `location`. There is an exceeding amount of poor logic in this.

```
location.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(location.getLatitude())));
location.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(location.getLongitude())));
```

location.getLatitude is the latitude, you do not need to set it.

You need to set a decimal separator:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
```

From here: [(android) decimalformat, uses comma in place of fullstop while formatting with "#.##"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557135/android-decimalformat-uses-comma-in-place-of-fullstop-while-formatting-with)

Also:

Get location.

```
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

For the purposes of your app, you do not need to change this.

Just pass the values to the server that you need:

```
String lat = decimalFormat(latitude);
String long = decimalFormat(longitude);
```

Comment: Actually I DO! I need to send to the server locations that contain just 5 decimals for the latitude and longitude.
Which means: 52.367991324 MUST become: 52.36799.
Now if you have an better version to do this, let me know. I did it like this, because not knowing how many decimals I get for the lat and long, I cannot divide to get 5 decimals